# does AWS CLI requires default profile as mandatory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

i am trying to fetch VPC details for all region.i tried to run my script without default profile which results in error  "You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure" ,evnthough i have my own profile configured with all required details for it.
same script works fine after configuring default profile.
Question is does AWS CLI requires default profile as mandatory ?
My script

```sh
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions  --output text| cut -f4`
do
aws ec2 --profile sam  --region $region --output text --query 'Vpcs[*].{VpcId:VpcId,CidrBlock:CidrBlock}' 
describe-vpcs
done
```

```sh
cat .aws/config
[profile sam]
output = json
region = us-east-1
```

Comment: What does `aws ec2 describe-regions  --output text` give you, without the cut or anything else? Anything there that doesn’t look like an AWS region name?

Comment: here is sample output for "aws ec2 describe-regions --output text"
REGIONS ec2.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com    opt-in-not-required     eu-north-1
REGIONS ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com    opt-in-not-required     ap-south-1
REGIONS ec2.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com     opt-in-not-required     eu-west-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t have a default profile configured, you can define the target profile with the --profile option.

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --profile profile-name
```

Another way is to set the AWS_PROFILE environment variable. This way you don’t have to explicitly add the option for every AWS CLI command.

```
export AWS_PROFILE=profile-name
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis. export AWS_PROFILE=profile-name , this could be useful for me to avoid redundancy ,i am writing a script.

Comment: Exactly. And NOT having a default profile can actually be a great choice, as you can never accidentally execute anything against the wrong profile because you forgot to add an explicit profile. I found myself multiple times quite confused with what was our wasn’t  happening in my accounts until I realized I was using the default profile instead of the one I wanted.

Comment: so running describe-regions without specifying the region is impossible? how do I know it  before running the command? ridiculous!

Comment: @Suncatcher: It is not at all ridiculous. The EC2 describe-regions API is there to be able to programmatically determine available regions at runtime and not intended as user documentation. Due to the fact that every AWS API calls need to have specific target, including the region, the region naturally needs to be specified as part of the call. If you don’t know any of the available regions, you can always refer to the AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html#Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.Availability

Comment: and what if I need to fetch this list in my script to later build the commands based on it? is there any way to fetch the regions in a region-agnostic way?

Comment: You have to start somewhere and an API call needs a target. Just use “us-east-1” to start with and go from there. Can we agree that things don’t need to be made more complicated than they actually are just for the sake of an argument?

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bug in your script. I tried the below and it worked for me.

```
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions  --output text| cut -f4`
do
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --profile <myProfile>  --region $region --output text --query 'Vpcs[*].{VpcId:VpcId,CidrBlock:CidrBlock}'
done
```

Comment: do you have default profile configured ? .. the script works when someone configures default profile ,, then only it picks up their respective user-profile.. I tried above script still same issue

Comment: I have a default profile configured. Let me give a try without one.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue , need to add --profile in my first line of code as well.It works fine now.

```
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions  --profile sam --output text| cut -f4
```

Comment: If you wish to obtain the name of the region, use `aws ec2 describe-regions  --query Regions[].[RegionName] --output text`. There is no need to pipe the output through `cut`.